# Decode and reformat values from Serial data array

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio

My application receives data from a serial interface. Some received records can displayed directly to a textbox, others have to be converted. One Serial Messages that i have to decode contains 512byte and multiple informations.

To receive Data i use:

```
    private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        dataDecoder(data);         
    }
```

And in the data decoder i do the following:

```
        private void dataDecoder(string input)
    {
        string post = "";                       //empty string
        char[] buf = input.ToCharArray();       //Converter input String to Char Array

        if (buf[0] == '#')                       //only process records starting with #, others go directly to SetText(string)
        {
            post += "Decode, Len=";                                      //Informal message   
            int up = int.Parse(buf[2].ToString());                       //Upper byte of 16bit-binary integer
            int low = int.Parse(buf[3].ToString());                      //lower byte of 16bit-binary integer
            int len = low << 8 | up;                                     //converter to decimal int
            post += len;                                                 //edit string
            post += " Channel: ";                                        //informal message
            int first = int.Parse(buf[4].ToString());                    //Upper byte of 16bit-binary integer
            int second = int.Parse(buf[5].ToString());                   //lower byte of 16bit-binary integer
            int chnl = second << 8 | first;                              //converter to decimal int
            post += chnl;                                                //edit string
            post += "DATA";                                              //informal message


            for (int i = 0; i < 507; i++)                                  //decode contents 6 to 511 (512byte is checsum)
            {
                int k = i + 6;                                           //format selector
                int one = int.Parse(buf[k].ToString());                  //Highest byte of 32bit-binary integer
                int two = int.Parse(buf[k + 1].ToString());                //second high byte of 32bit-binary integer
                int three = int.Parse(buf[k + 2].ToString());            //second low byte of 32bit-binary integer
                int four = int.Parse(buf[k + 3].ToString());             //lowest byte of 32bit-binary integer
                int rec = four << 24 | three << 16 | two << 8 | one;     //convert to decimal int
                post += rec;                                             //edit string                  
                post += ",";                                             //separation character
            }
            SetText(post);                                               //set text to texbox
        }
        else
        {
            SetText(input);                                              //set input to textbox (unconverted)
        }
    }
}
```

Build does not report any errors or warnings. But when i run the code and it reaches this function, the program does crash with the message

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

on the line

```
int up = int.Parse(buf[2].ToString());
```

What could i do better to solve this issue?

**EDIT**
Here is the first parts of the Serial data (taken from Serial Monitor)

> 23 42 FC 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

23 is #
42 is B
and FC 01 is the record lenght, in this case is known, and its 508 (01FC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what data format you have, but you can use regex or custom mapping as shown below.

```
public static unsafe void dataDecoder(string input)
{
    switch (input[0])
    {
        case '#':
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            Map(bytes);
            break;
    }
}

public static unsafe string Map(this byte[] bytes)
{
    
    var offset = 2;
    var post = string.Empty;
    if (bytes == null)
        return post;

    //while (bytes.Length < offset)
    {
        int len =0
        int chnl =0;
        fixed (byte* numPtr = &bytes[offset])
        {
            len = *(Int16*)numPtr;
        }
        offset += 2;
        post += len;                                                 
        post += " Channel: ";                                        

        fixed (byte* numPtr = &bytes[offset])
        {
            chnl = *(Int16*)numPtr;
        }
        offset += 2;
        

    }
    // etc...
    return post;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "takes up one char" ? A char can be 16 bit in C# and int is 32 bit, so i think it cannot be larger. Also you use string[0], which i tried before, but i've read posts that this cant be done in C# because string is immutable.

Comment: you can use unsafe code and read data by pointer as in example. At first we skip first byte '#', second get len Int16

Comment: it will be your Length:  fixed (byte* numPtr = &bytes[2])
        {
            len = *(Int16*)numPtr;
        }

Comment: I meant that Int16 can take up 2 bytes (FF FF), or if stored in a string representation of 5 bytes '32767' - in ASCII